# knockout.js observable is not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, observable

Team,

### I have a very simple html page with a viewmodel as follows.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='E:\Trials\ClientSide\MyTrials\knockout-2.2.1.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='E:\Trials\ClientSide\MyTrials\jquery-2.0.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function PersonViewModel()
        {
            firstName = ko.observable("FirstN")
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var person = new PersonViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(person);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Details</h3>
        <p>First Name: <input data-bind="value:  firstName()" /></p>
        <p>First Name From span: <span data-bind="text: firstName()" ></span> </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Its very simple and self explanatory. script block contains a view model, and on doc ready function, binding happens. And the html is also simple enough. One input and one span bound to same property firstName which is observable. 
But the pain is when I change the value from the input, the span does not update. What am I missing?
Regards
Vivek

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `firstName()` to `firstName`

```
<p>First Name: <input data-bind="value:  firstName" /></p>
<p>First Name From span: <span data-bind="text: firstName" ></span> </p>
```

Comment: went on for 4 hours straight and even tried valuehasMutated function but this solved it. Thank you so much Claudio

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems here.

1. As mentioned by Caludio, you are placing the brackets in your binding when it is not necessary. Refer to his answer for how to fix this.
2. Your PersonViewModel is slightly wrong. You have forgotten to place the 'this.' in front of the firstName property. Fix it like so:

   ```
   function PersonViewModel()
   {
       this.firstName = ko.observable("FirstN");
   };
   ```

Comment: Hi, Caludio's suggestioin worked. Rodney suggested to add "this". But I found it is not required to add. I just removed "()" and it worked.

Comment: Yes you are right, for the very simple example that you have provided you can get away with not adding the 'this' keyword in front of your model properties. But I strongly suggest you start making a habit of it, otherwise when your models become more complicated you will start seeing some strange errors. I have created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8LuF8/2/ to demonstrate.

Comment: You absolutely want to use 'this' here because that will actually make `firstName` a property of `PersionViewModel`. The reason why the code still works is because `firstName` is being created as an object in the global scope, and so the Knockout binding code can still access that property just by name, but it is in the wrong scope.